# How can i download all the htmls and save them one one loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\\Sat24_Rain_Europe.html");
client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=2&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\\Sat24_Wind_Europe.html");
client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=3&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\\Sat24_Lightnings_europe.html");
client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=0&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\\Sat24_Temperature_Europe.html");
client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=4&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\\Sat24_Cloudtypes_Europe.html");
```

But instead downloading each time to make a loop that will run through the htmls like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                          client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=i&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\\Sat24_Cloudtypes_Europe.html");
                        }
```

Instead 0 1 2 3 4...using (i) in the loop.

But if i change client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=4&continent=europa#", localFilename + "\Sat24_Cloudtypes_Europe.html");

The number 4 to i so the variable i will be in blue like part of the url and not a as variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var files = new Dictionary<int, string> {
   { 0, "Sat24_Temperature_Europe.html" },
   { 1, "Sat24_Rain_Europe.html" },
   { 2, "Sat24_Wind_Europe.html" },
   { 3, "Sat24_Lightnings_europe.html" },
   { 4, "Sat24_Cloudtypes_Europe.html" }
};

const string urlFormat = 
                  "http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type={0}&continent=europa#";
foreach (var kv in files)
{
    string url = string.Format(urlFormat, kv.Key);
    client.DownloadFile(url, localFilename + "\\" + kv.Value);
}
```